# Programatically extract outline of knitr Rmd

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, quarto

Is there a way to extract chunk labels and locations with knitr (is there a built-in knitr function)

```r
knitr::f(path = "file.qmd")
#> chunk-1 : line 4
#> fig-one : line 7
etc.
```

I guess you can do it within the file. with `knitr::all_labels()`

But is there a way to map it?

Also, is it possible to extract a document outline in RStudio?